# How to use async await promises for API calls in cypress

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, cypress

I would like to know why the same test case result is 4xx, 5xx, 2xx on every try? How can I avoid it? Might it be related to waiting?

P.S. I talked to the DevOps team they said the env is stable.

Comment: Looks like the API cannot find the vehicle id. That could be a bug, wrong id you store into `vehicleIdBuyNow`, or something deletes your vehicle id before the request hits the backend. Have you eliminated these options? Cypress doesn't seem like a probable culprit here.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added 1 more screen. there is some other problem. Because if I run constantly the same test case without changing anything, my test case is running properly

Comment: So what have you changed between the first and second screen? The vehicle id? But still, why would you think there's something wrong with your check or Cypress? Perhaps that's how the system works, perhaps it's a bug, perhaps you don't know fully how the system works. If you buy a vehicle, I suppose the vehicle it is not available then, so future requests return 404. That's what I assume based on the information given. Is it correct? I don't know.

Comment: I did not change anything. I just re - run the same test case

Comment: Then I suppose you can't use the same vehicle id more than once. If you buy one vehicle, it's not available anymore for future purchases. I assume that might be how the system works and that it is desired. But it doesn't look like something is wrong with your Cypress request, it's more related to business logic.

Comment: 1. I run tets case I got 4xx
2. I re-run tes case I got 5xx
3. I re-run test case I got 2xx
there is nothing related to business logic..
something wrong with my async, that is why I am here to ask the reason and request for help

Comment: What happens if you send the same request multiple times using Postman for example? Does it work then? Have you checked it already? This will tell you for sure that Cypress is (not) a problem. As I can only agree with @pavelsaman here, doesn't look like Cypress error.

Comment: yes I tried via postman. It works fine. No problem response in there

Comment: Can you show us the part of the code that sets `vehicleIdBuyNow`, my next assumption would be that this isn't set properly sometimes. Or can you examine the failed requests to see if something is missing in the body perhaps?

Comment: " it.only("buy a fix priced vehicle", () => {
    const minPrice = 26350;
  
    const vehicleIdBuyNow = "30f269ac675813a68885ce336971d897";
    
    const platformUserIdBuyNow = 0;"

Comment: `cy.wait(2000)` is useless in your example due to a couple of reasons: 1. the request has been performed by the time of the wait. 2. due to the anync nature of cy commands, the statements below the wait will be executed **before** the actual waiting

Comment: Damn, I'm out of ideas. Last question, what's the 500 code error message?

Comment: Luna, you might want to consider a recursive function for your request as per documentation https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request#Request-Polling

Comment: @Zaista the error message is "CriticalException" "index_not_found_exception

Comment: `index_not_found_exception` is an Elasticsearch exception. Which would mean that elasticsearch is not in sync with your db at the moment of your request

Comment: @AlexIzbas thank you so much for this answer. I feel relief